Compare if a value from one dataframe is in the list of values of another
Consider these two dfs:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 103, 3: 104},
    'Number': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'B1'}})

    Id  Number
0   101 A1
1   102 A2
2   103 B1
3   104 B1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Client': {0: 'John', 1: 'Mia', 2: 'Claudia'},
    'Number': {0: ['A1', 'B1'], 1: ['Z4'], 2: ['A2']}})

    Client  Number
0   John    [A1, B1]
1   Mia     [Z4]
2   Claudia [A2]

How do I check if values from df1["Number"] are in df2["Number"] and append all the corresponding ids from df1["Id"]? So the results are like this?
    Client  Number   Ids
0   John    [A1, B1] [101, 103, 104]
1   Mia     [Z4]     NaN
2   Claudia [A2]     [102]


The Number column in df2 that you provided is a string, not a list. Is it correct that it is a string, and if so, is the Ids column in your desired output also a string? Your title and tags say list, but the example you provided is a string with square brackets.

thanks for pointing it out, I've corrected. Will try be more attentive next time @wjandrea

You can use a custom function and indexing:
def mapper(lst, ref):
    idx = [x for x in lst.strip('[]').split(', ') if x in ref.index]
    return ref.loc[idx].tolist() if idx else None

df2['Ids'] = df2['Number'].apply(mapper, ref=df1.set_index('Number')['Id'])

If your inputs in df2 are lists (not strings), simplify to:
def mapper(lst, ref):
    idx = [x for x in lst if x in ref.index]
    return ref.loc[idx].tolist() if idx else None

Variant using Index.intersection (suggested by @wjandrea):
def mapper(lst, ref):
    idx = ref.index.intersection(lst)
    return None if idx.empty else ref.loc[idx].tolist()

df2['Ids'] = df2['Number'].apply(mapper, ref=df1.set_index('Number')['Id'])

Output:
    Client    Number              Ids
0     John  [A1, B1]  [101, 103, 104]
1      Mia      [Z4]             None
2  Claudia      [A2]            [102]


Simpler: idx = ref.index.intersection(...) and ... if not idx.empty else None

This worked for me:
def find_ids(row):
    numbers = row["Number"]
    matches = df1.loc[df1["Number"].isin(numbers)]
    return matches["Id"].tolist() or float('NaN')

df2["Ids"] = df2.apply(find_ids, axis=1)


You can simplify the code by looping over the column instead of the df: def find_ids(numbers): and df2["Number"].apply(find_ids)

First, I recommend using a list of strings in the Number column of df2, instead of a single string with brackets and commas. If this isn't possible, see the workaround at the end. The initial dataframes would look like this:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Id': {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 103, 3: 104},
        'Number': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'B1'},
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Client': {0: 'John', 1: 'Mia', 2: 'Claudia'},
        'Number': {0: '[A1, B1]', 1: '[Z4]', 2: '[A2]'},
    }
)

Now we can create a column with empty lists and fill them with the Ids.
Note: I'm not claiming this is the fastest or most human-readable solution. It's just the first method I found.
df2['Ids'] = df2.shape[0] * [[]]

for row, number_lst in df2['Number'].items():
    for number in number_lst:
        df2['Ids'].iloc[row] = (
            df2['Ids'].iloc[row] + df1[df1['Number'] == number]['Id'].to_list()
        )

The result would be this:
    Client  Number  Ids
0   John    [A1, B1]    [101, 103, 104]
1   Mia     [Z4]        []
2   Claudia [A2]        [102]

Please note that Mia's entry displays an empty list instead of NaN as per your request. You can resolve this by including the following line at the end:
import numpy as np

df2.loc[df2['Ids'].isin([[]]), 'Ids'] = np.nan

Alternative solution for manipulating df2 with a single string containing brackets and commas instead of a list of strings.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Client': {0: 'John', 1: 'Mia', 2: 'Claudia'},
        'Number': {0: '[A1, B1]', 1: '[Z4]', 2: '[A2]'},
    }
)

for row, number_lst in df2['Number'].items():
    df2['Number'].iloc[row] = number_lst.strip('[]').replace(" ", "").split(',')

Finally, here is the full code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Original dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Id': {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 103, 3: 104},
        'Number': {0: 'A1', 1: 'A2', 2: 'B1', 3: 'B1'},
    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Client': {0: 'John', 1: 'Mia', 2: 'Claudia'},
        'Number': {0: '[A1, B1]', 1: '[Z4]', 2: '[A2]'},
    }
)

# # Uncomment this to create the second dataframe as I suggested:
# df2 = pd.DataFrame(
#     {
#         'Client': {0: 'John', 1: 'Mia', 2: 'Claudia'},
#         'Number': {0: ['A1', 'B1'], 1: ['Z4'], 2: ['A2']},
#     }
# )

# Coment/remove this if you used the second creation sugestion.
for row, number_lst in df2['Number'].items():
    df2['Number'].iloc[row] = number_lst.strip('[]').replace(" ", "").split(',')

df2['Ids'] = df2.shape[0] * [[]]

for row, number_lst in df2['Number'].items():
    for number in number_lst:
        df2['Ids'].iloc[row] = (
            df2['Ids'].iloc[row] + df1[df1['Number'] == number]['Id'].to_list()
        )

# Coment/remove this if than NaN aren't important, use empty lists instead.
df2.loc[df2['Ids'].isin([[]]), 'Ids'] = np.nan


thanks! I made an error (errors actually) when posting a question, should be lists indeed. sorry for confusion
